# Import DXF defined padstacks in to Allegro/Orcad PCB

Tags: footprint, orcad, allegro, dxf

I'm using Orcad PCB Professional 17.4-2019 S017

I've got a symbol with some funky pads on it, one the padstack editor cannot generate.

Here's where I'm trying to get to. Green is mask boundary, blue is top etch, Grey is paste, red is package boundary, white is silk, purple is construction lines.
Note the goofy pads on the corners.
[image: VQFN Target Drawing]

I know you can create a new flash symbol drawing and import a DXF in to it, save the flash, and use that in the Padstack editor. That is going to be more painful than I think it ought to be. The pads are more than rotationally different from each other.

Anyway, what I would *like* to do is design the symbol in Orcad PCB Pro such that the symbol is close to the real design, export a DXF, modify the problematic pads in AutoCAD, and bring the DXF back in, and export the new modified padstacks.

The section in the manual called "DXF Bi-Directional Interface" makes me think such a thing is possible. There is even a "PADSTACK" block section in the DXF file.

I made the following symbol in Allegro to get me close.

[image: Allegro Symbol Close to target]

Export the above symbol in DXF using the following settings:

[image: DXF Out options]

And using the attached CNV file (At the bottom).

And when I just reimport the DXF file unchanged, using the following settings:
[image: DXF In options]

I Receive the following error:
[image: Error Dialog]

And the symbol drawing appears broken.

I would love some tips or help.

Incase the CNV file didnt' attach, here's the text of it (forgive the formatting):

```
#This is the Layer Conversion File used for
#importing DXF data into Allegro/APD.

#CLASS!            SUBCLASS!                           DXF_LAYER!

COMPONENT VALUE!
                   SILKSCREEN_TOP!                     CV_SILKSCREEN_TOP!
                   ASSEMBLY_TOP!                       CV_ASSEMBLY_TOP!

DEVICE TYPE!
                   SILKSCREEN_TOP!                     DT_SILKSCREEN_TOP!
                   ASSEMBLY_TOP!                       DT_ASSEMBLY_TOP!

ETCH!
                   TOP!                                ET_TOP!

PACKAGE GEOMETRY!
                   SOLDERMASK_TOP!                     PG_SOLDERMASK_TOP!
                   BODY_CENTER!                        PG_BODY_CENTER!
                   SILKSCREEN_TOP!                     PG_SILKSCREEN_TOP!
                   PIN_NUMBER!                         PG_PIN_NUMBER!
                   PLACE_BOUND_TOP!                    PG_PLACE_BOUND_TOP!
                   ASSEMBLY_TOP!                       PG_ASSEMBLY_TOP!

PIN!
                   TOP!                                PIN_TOP!
                   BOTTOM!                             PIN_BOTTOM!
                   FILMMASKBOTTOM!                     PIN_FILMMASKBOTTOM!
                   FILMMASKTOP!                        PIN_FILMMASKTOP!
                   PASTEMASK_BOTTOM!                   PIN_PASTEMASK_BOTTOM!
                   PASTEMASK_TOP!                      PIN_PASTEMASK_TOP!
                   SOLDERMASK_BOTTOM!                  PIN_SOLDERMASK_BOTTOM!
                   SOLDERMASK_TOP!                     PIN_SOLDERMASK_TOP!

REF DES!
                   SILKSCREEN_TOP!                     RD_SILKSCREEN_TOP!
                   ASSEMBLY_TOP!                       RD_ASSEMBLY_TOP!

#END
```

Thanks!